# Openshift Scaling Tomcat7 with Stored Files and Images

Tags: tomcat7, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise, openshift-cartridge

If I have a Gear which contains Files and Images uploaded by Users, will the directory be Shared across all Gears? or will it be synced after every User upload?

If not, is there any workaround?
Can I manually sync all Gears after every user upload/delete/change in the upload directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that are uploaded by users into your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR will not be synced in a scalable application.  The resolution for this issue is to use a third party file hosting service such as Amazon S3.